# SharePoint 2013 App: 'Object' not defined (IFrame / IE9)

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-9, sharepoint-2013

When developing an (SharePoint hosted) App Part for SharePoint 2013 I continiously get the error message 'Object' not defined. On other occassions (depending on which external .js file I'm loading) I might get an 'Function' not defined error. To be more specific: I only get this error, when I'm adding the App Part to a (wiki) page. The page is loaded in IE9 in Standards mode (but the error also happens in Compat View).

I found the following Information at Microsoft: APIs Are Not Available if iFrame Is Removed from DOM Tree => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622929(v=VS.85).aspx?ppud=4

I've added a simple alert to the head of the HTML page I'm trying to load as the source of the App Part (which is in fact a simple IFrame object) and indeed the page is loaded multiple times when adding the App Part. Once the App Part is added, the alert is only triggered once and I don't experience any 'Object' not defined errors. So I suspect that my App Part is first created and then manipulated several times (being attached and detached from the DOM).

It seems that my App Part, because it's temporarily removed from the DOM removes the JavaScript API! If that is the case, then how can I develop App Parts that rely on JavaScript (and shouldn't they not rely on JavaScript in the first place?!) ...

Answer (score 0):

I can "surpress" this behaviour if I reload the page untill the JavaScript API is available again (this seems to be after the last time the IFrame was detached and attached again). I therefore simply put the following script as the first statement in the page's head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Work-around for IE9 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622929(v=VS.85).aspx?ppud=4)
    if (typeof Object == 'undefined' || typeof Function == 'undefined') {
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Still, this "pre-emptive" collection of garbage to me seems a bug rather than a feature!